# Wild Card search in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a large database of product names that has been collected in different times and some of the names have slightly changed. For example, the table below shows the changes in the product names.

[image]

Most common differences are:

capital/non-capital letters
spaces
"-" or without
Cigar vs Cigars, vs Cg
Different variants of No. (eg. N, No, No.)
with or without "'"
"1 single" vs "single", vs "single cigar"
missing "of" (eg. Box of 10, box 10) etc...

I have tried VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP but they did not work - i am guessing its to complex for them to identify the changes. Is there any other way I could solve this?

Comment: You can use the Fuzzy Lookup addin by microsoft and see if that helps.

Comment: What is your expected output?  What are you trying to do with the data?  There is a fuzzy lookup addin. Power Query also has fuzzy matching capabilities.

Comment: I will give fuzzy lookup a try, thank you @ScottCraner, Ron Rosenfield